# How to get UIButton position during animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.f target:self selector:@selector(creatButton) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

}

```
- (NSMutableArray *)buttonsArray {
if (!_buttonsArray) {
    _buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return _buttonsArray;
```

}

```
- (void)creatButton {
NSInteger j = arc4random() % 250;
UIButton *countButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((j * 20) % ((NSInteger)self.view.frame.size.width - 120), -300, 100, 50)];

[self.buttonsArray addObject:countButton];

[self.view addSubview:countButton];

[UIView animateWithDuration:9 delay:0.f
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear)
                    animations:^{

                        countButton.center = CGPointMake(50 + (j * 20) % ((NSInteger)self.view.frame.size.width - 120), self.view.frame.size.height);
                    }
                    completion:nil];
```

}

and I want to know has any way to get `countButton`'s position while the animation is "in-flight".

Comment: Try [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; But I do think timer is not a good practice in this case. Maybe you can also check CADisplayLink.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is a reasonable question. Granted, the wording of the title was a little awkward, but it was easy enough to figure out what he was asking from the rest of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James Baxter's answer is the right way to go. You need to query the presentationLayer that's being animated.

Note that UIView animations use CAAnimations under the covers, so it's possible to interrogate the position of a view that's being animated by a UIView animation the same way.

I have a demo project on Github called [iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo)  that demonstrates a number of techniques including "hit testing" in-flight UIView and CAAnimation animations so you can click on an image that's animating to pause/resume the animation. It's written in Objective-C, but it looks like that's what you want, so it should b helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much Duncan C, your project is very helpful

Comment: No problem. You should accept James Baxter's answer, since he's the one who told you the correct approach. (My answer was more of an "assist" to his answer, truth be told.)

Answer (score 3):

The way view animation is configured in UIKit/CoreAnimation, as soon as an animation block is called, the view's properties are set to the final value, so reading `counterButton.center` will only return the final value.  Similarly, the layer's properties are probably pinned to the final value (though not strictly by necessity).

What you can do is use the view's layer's presentation layer, `[countButton.layer presentationLayer]`, to get an approximate snapshot of the layer's properties as they appear on screen.

[From Apple, emphasis added](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentationlayer?language=objc):

> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> - (instancetype)presentationLayer;
> ```
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A copy of the current presentation layer object.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The layer object returned by this method provides ***a close approximation of the layer that is currently being displayed onscreen***. While an animation is in progress, you can retrieve this object and use it to get the current values for those animations.

By default, a view's center is the same as `view.layer.position`, so you could get the button's in-animation center with:

```
[countButton.layer presentationLayer].position
```

Comment: Good answer. (Voted.) You beat me to it.